# How Network Security Groups affect Azure VM IPs?

Tags: azure-networking, entra-domain-services

I have three classic Azure VMs in a sub-net with Domain Services enabled. Machines are joined to a domain and accessible via RD.

In order to apply a common set of inbound rules I created a Network Security Group and associate it to the VMs. As required, I had to remove the endpoints from the VM in order to attach the NSG.

After NSG were taken into use the machines can no longer be reached by using the Virtual IP. If I remove the NSG and re-add the Endpoint RDP works.

The only way to reach the VM with NSG attached was to toggle the switch for "Instance IP" and use this second IP from Remote Desktop.  I think I'm missing some fundamental points about how Azure Networks and NSG work. Please note that VMs were created in classic mode due to Azure a Domain Services requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> The only way to reach the VM with NSG attached was to toggle the
>   switch for "Instance IP" and use this second IP from Remote Desktop.

There are some difference between ASM and ARM.

The VM create in ASM module, it will create by a shared IP(NAT) and a FQDN, we can connect to this VM by **FQDN** or **public IP and port**.  If you want to use NSG with classic VM, we should use Instance IP.

The NSG in ARM module, it work with public IP address(ARM) by default.

In classic module, an endpoint Access Control List (ACL) is a security enhancement available for your Azure deployment. An ACL provides the ability to selectively permit or deny traffic for a virtual machine endpoint.

More information about ACLs, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-acl).

Comment: Your answer is not very clear, I'm afraid. What is ASM? What is "ARM module"? You wrote "if you want to use NSG with classic VM, we should use instance IP". Should use or have to use?

Comment: sorry, ASM mean classic module, ARM mean resource module.  If you want to use NSG with classic VM, we have to use instance IP.